# servlet request disptach forward not working when a request parameter contains values with carriage return/line break

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a popup window (parent-1) which has multiple input fields and a link. The fields in parent-1 window will be loaded with data from db.

The link in parent-1 window will open another child-1 popup which has a `<textarea>` for user to input text. This allows line breaks (Carriage Return - CR or /n).

In my case, once user inputs text in child-1 window `<textarea>`, upon closing the values are displayed in a read-only input field and also in a hidden `<textarea>` element.

When the parent-1 popup is submitted the form elements are sent to server side with POST request and stored in database. Once stored successfully a success message is displayed along with the loaded data in the fields with the modified input values.

After storing the data successfully, the code is using servlet dispatcher to forward the request. like below.

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/products.jsp?key1=value1").forward(request, response);
```

Issue is, when the textarea content has a CR or line break, the forward is not loading the values in the input fields, it clears out all the fields.

It works fine when the textarea content, didn't had any line breaks.

I debugged and also noticed that one of the request parameter is having the text content with line breaks, as it displayed in multiple lines. (as mentioned above, in this case, the servlet loaded but no values are populated in the input fields, all fields are blank)

But When i use `response.sendRedirect("/WEB-INF/products.jsp?key1=value1")`, it works in both cases was expected. I understand in sendRedirect the request is not passed to the servlet, in my case since the servlet had query parameters it reloaded the screen.

Any specific reason why the servlet request dispatcher forward didn't work when request parameter had line breaks in value?

---

Below code worked.

1. Created a Dynamic web project
2. converted to maven using `configure -> convert to maven`
   i. added below dependency in pom.xml,

```xml
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>taglibs-standard-spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>taglibs-standard-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

3. created index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

   
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Hello World Java EE</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello JSP and Servlet!</h1>

    <form action="helloServlet" method="post">
    <label>Name:
                <input type="text" name="name">
            </label>
        <textarea rows="5" cols="150" name="txtInputFromUser"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Call Servlet" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

4. helloMessage.jsp (the alert, in the console errors but still works)

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Hello Message</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <c:out value="${param.fromServer}" />
        Name: ${param.name}
        <script>
        alert('<c:out value="${param.txtInputFromUser}" />');
        </script>
    </div>
    <div>
        <textarea><c:out value="${param.txtInputFromUser}" /></textarea>
        <div>From server:- <c:out value="${param.fromServer}" /></div>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

5. Servlet code:

```java
package com.helloapp;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class HelloExample
 */
@WebServlet("/helloServlet")
public class HelloExample extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public HelloExample() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String input =request.getParameter("txtInputFromUser");
        System.out.println("reached here:- " + input);
        
        String fromServerCheck = request.getParameter("fromServer");
            response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/helloMessage.jsp?fromServer=yes");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

Comment: *the forward is not loading the values in the input fields*. A forward doesn't load anything. A forward is just that, a forward. The problem is most likely in the JSP file where you might somehow mishandle the data. Have you looked at the HTML source in the brrowser when the inputs values aren't displayed to see what's going on? Also, by any chance are you swallowing some exception, or is there some exception in the lserver logs?

Comment: I will check the html. I am i using tomcat 7, taglib 1. I wrote a simple servlet in 3.1 and I didn't had any issue. I notice when I used to dispaly the texarea content with line breaks the console reports error not stopping  from loading the page and the field. As u noted it might be the jsp itself. Also sine there are no exception it is hard to know what is happy.